# What is the opposite of highlighted, in a visual presentation

Tags: single-word-requests

Im looking for a word to describe the visual aspect of a user interface. Imagine a form to fill out, in a web page. Disabled fields will be grayed out, and draw less attention. The opposite of highlighted.

I have a similar situation, but the fields are in fact not disabled, I just want to mark them as less significant than the others. In order to be able to reuse the style, I'd like to name the style something that means the opposite of highlighted.

These are the antonyms I have found, but none of them really works:

**lowlight** - Never heard this word actually used. Might work?
**disappointment** - No go in a visual context
**nonevent**  - No go in a visual context
**anticlimax**  - No go in a visual context
**bringdown** - Never heard this word actually used. Might work?
**downer** - No go in a visual context
**downfall** - No go in a visual context
**letdown** - No go in a visual context
**let-down** - No go in a visual context
**washout** - Maybe?
**nadir** - Not understandable to most people, me included
**low point**  - No go in a visual context

So, does any of these work for my situation? Or are there any others that I haven't found?

Comment: Depending on how you "de-highlight" your fields you may describe them as drenched (I found some antonyms of highlighted here: [https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/highlighted?s=t](thesaurus.com)

Comment: I would never understand drenched to mean de-highlighted in this (or any) context. But i kind of like de-highlighted. Though it pretty much means not highlighted, it might be enough to get my point across :)

Comment: First, "+1" for explicitly exploring and rejecting commonly-found antonyms (too many don't). When you say "_I just want to mark them as less significant than the others_" does that mean you will have _highlighted_ fields (more important than normal), _normal_ fields (normal importance) and _???_ fields (less important than normal)? Or are you just going to have highlighted fields and not-highlighted fields?

Comment: I have a list of items, based of templates. It looks like a table, but with input fields for text and stuff. In this editor, I'd like to play down the rows that are not yet (or might never be) actually instantiated from template. Meaning they will not be visible for those with reading rights, and should therefor have a different visual style (less significant) than the actual instantiated rows. Fields will only be highlighted when there are unsaved changes in the editor.

Comment: You could describe them as de-emphasised.

Comment: Perhaps "downplayed".

Comment: I would use ‘greyed out’ - if they are greyed out ie unavailable to click on, and un-highlighted if they are normal text. Or even say ‘plain text’ or ‘normal text’.  I would not use drenched (that sounds wierd) or lowlighted as I don’t think those convey a clear meaning.

Comment: If some text does not appear at all (but you still want to describe it), then those could be ‘non-displayed fields’ or ‘non-displayed text’.

Comment: Deaccentuate? First thing that comes to mind...

Comment: I like your own later suggestion of toned down.

Comment: _Lowdarked_, clearly.

Comment: lowdarked is the new official word, at least in my world :)

Answer (score 2):

I've mostly heard of lowlights in terms of sports events or [careers](https://sallywatson.com.au/2017-career-highlights-lowlights/)

However while trying to find references for that meaning I found one to do with [hair colouring](https://www.sofeminine.co.uk/hair/lowlights-vs-highlights-s572758.html)

> Lowlights versus highlights
>
> Lowlights involve darkening strands of hair by using colours that are darker than your natural colour. In contrast, highlights use colours that are lighter than your natural shade.

So if the negative highlighting you are doing involves shading (bright vs dark) rather than changing the colour, I think *lowlight/lowlights/lowlighting* is perfect.

Comment: might go with lowlighted... Or maybe just toned down?

Comment: *downlight(s)* or  *downlighted*? Although more of a physical direction of lighting then brightness/shading. 2nd one is also not a proper word.

Answer (score 0):

If something is *highlighted*, it is also *emphasized*. Therefore, as a verb, the opposite would be [**de-emphasized**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/de-emphasize):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : to reduce in relative importance
>   *also* : PLAY DOWN

An example sentence for the scenario in the question is as follows:

> I highlighted some aspects, but *de-emphasized* others.

---

Note, too, the possible use of *reduced*.

Answer (score 0):

The verb to [background](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/background) could work. Merriam Websters:

> 2 : to give less attention or emphasis to (something) : to place
>   (something) in the background 
> *Graham peoples her novel with genuine,
>   endearing characters and keeps the grisly murders tactfully
>   backgrounded* … — Publishers Weekly Reviews

In your case, you could *background the less important information*.